# How long it takes to start Bind?

Tags: time, startup, bind, dnssec

I'm testing DNSSEC and I need to obtain the time in miliseconds it takes to start Bind now that I have signed zones. I don't know if this would be the right way to do it:

```
time svcadm enable svc:/network/dns/server:default
```

Regards,
Arancha

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get a pretty good hint as to the time-to-ready of BIND by looking at the 'general' logging category (logged by default to 'default_syslog') during system start.

Note that loading a DNSSEC signed zone will not take significantly longer than loading a non-signed zone (taking into account the larger number of RRsets).